# Squash all commits in branch in git

Tags: git, squash

Say I have a number of commits in the feature branch from last commit in master

```
... - last_commit_in_master - C1 - C2 - .. - C100
```

Now I want to merge all those commits into a single one.

I know one solution:

- `git rebase -i master`
- replace all the pick except first one. Yoohoo, there is `2,s/pick/squash/` in vim. <-- that's a step I don't like to do each time
- choose new commit name.

Is there way to do it easier?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing squash, replace each except the first with fixup, and then you don't have to choose a new commit name, it just puts them all in the same commit.

Comment: Well, review old commits and choose a new name is not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are combining all commits into one, and you want the commit message and time of the last commit.

```
git reset --soft $(git merge-base HEAD master)
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

(This will let you re-edit the message if you want to tweak it.)

This will not rebase. Do that in a separate step.